# How can I invoke C# private Method<T>?, NUnit Testing

Tags: c#, nunit, invoke

I am trying to test a generic method but NUnit gives System.InvalidOperationException ... ContainsGenericParameters is true.

I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

There is the test code:

```
[Test]
    [Category("Private")]
    public async void TestConfirmedSendAsync()
    {
        var privProxy = new PrivateObject(_proxy);
        var task = (Task)privProxy.Invoke("ConfirmedAsyncTask");
        await task;
    }
```

And the method call is:

```
private async Task ConfirmedSendAsync<T>()
```

How can I make the generic call?

The only way I could make it (without breaking private) is by creating private methods for each type I need...

```
private async Task ConfirmedSendStringAsync() { await ConfirmedSendAsync<string>();}
```

And the test:

```
[Test]
    [Category("Private")]
    public async void TestConfirmedSendAsync()
    {
        var privProxy = new PrivateObject(_proxy);
        var task = (Task)privProxy.Invoke("ConfirmedAsyncTaskString");
        await task;
    }
```

Comment: By making it `public async Task ConfirmedSendAsync<T>()`

Comment: I would like to keep ConfirmedSendAsync private. Have I any option to make it?